# Eclipse: How can I set the {user} variable?

Tags: eclipse, configuration

I'm using Eclipse (v3.5.2 to be exact), and the several of the plugins I'm using use the `{user}` field to populate various things (for instance, Egit puts the username and email address in commits, and the StatEt plugin for R puts the username as the Authour tags in roxygen Rd doc files.)

However, On my system my username is meaningless to anyone outside of the company.  Is it possible to change this field to something more sensible like "Paul Hurley" (and similarly to set an email address), either manually, via a configuration or via some script on load ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always modify some eclipse settings in ECLIPSE_HOME\eclipse.ini file.

```
-Duser.country=EN
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.name=Matthieu BROUILLARD [matthieu@somewhere.org]
```

Overriding those properties is very usefull especially for bad translation in your local language. For me for example SVN plugins are really difficult to use with french translation.

Hope this helps.